# If $A$ and $B$ are transition matrices such that $||A-B|| < c$, then what can we say about $||A^n-B^n||$ for a given $n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, markov-chains, transition-matrix, stochastic-matrices

Suppose there are two matrices, $A$ and $B$, that are both transition matrices for a Markov chain ($n\times n$, non-negative and row-stochastic). I know that A and B are "close" in the sense that $||A-B||< c$ for some constant c. Is there anything I could say about the upper bound on $||A^t - B^t||$ for $t < \infty$?

Comment: Perron-Frobenius Theorem